# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException

Tags: java, neo4j, java-io

While executing Neo4j testcases. I am facing below error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException:test-data/org.neo4j.test.ha.ClusterTest/D4FA83E7CD83F51509461D8F437E0481/testConflictingHaPorts
        at org.neo4j.test.rule.TestDirectory.complete(TestDirectory.java:211)
        at org.neo4j.test.rule.TestDirectory.access$200(TestDirectory.java:57)
        at org.neo4j.test.rule.TestDirectory$1.evaluate(TestDirectory.java:113)
        at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:254)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:149)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

Looks like it is unable to delete the directory and hence facing the above execption. The user has all the permissions granted.

Below code snippet is used to delete the directory

```
 public void evaluate() throws Throwable
            {
                directory = new File( new File( new File( new File( "target" ), "test-data" ),
                                                description.getClassName() ), description.getMethodName() );
                delete( directory );
                directory.mkdirs();
                boolean success = false;
                try
                {
                    base.evaluate();
                    success = true;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if ( success )
                    {
                        delete( directory );
                        delete( directory.getParentFile() ); // works if it's empty
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: The directory is not empty. Try clear the directory before deleting it.

Comment: I had deleted the directory contents, but it didn't work. I think it tried to create and delete the directory in the same code snippet.

Comment: What OS are you running on?  Are there any hidden files?

Comment: I am working on Red Hat Enterprise Linux operating system. Yes, there are some hidden files present.

Comment: Were the hidden files still present when you tried to delete the directory?  If so, they will prevent deletion.  You have to make sure you use a command that can work with hidden files such as `ls -a` to see if they're still there.

Comment: No, I had deleted the hidden files manually.

Comment: The directory is created at runtime and there are no hidden files present in that directory